# Resize image output file name issue

Tags: php, gd

I'm having an issue with the code below, for some reason I get the following error:

```
**Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource**
```

Using the following code:

```
$image = "image1.png";
$output = "filename.jpg";

// Call function
$img = resize_image($image, $output);

function resize_image($file, $output) {
  imagejpeg($img, $output, 60);
}
```

I'm basically trying to pass in the output filename (`$output = "filename.jpg";`) into the `imagejpeg()` function but getting the above error.

Comment: you couldn't do that, `imagejpeg` requires `resource` parameter, not `string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your input parameter is the issue.  Try this:

```
$image = "image1.png";
$output = "filename.jpg";

// Call function
$img = resize_image($image, $output);

function resize_image($file, $output) {
  imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg($img), $output, 60);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It says in the documentation that you need to pass a parameter to that function that is of type resource.  In other words, you need to create an image resource object using an image creation function, such as imagecreatetruecolor():

> image - An image resource, returned by one of the image creation
>   functions, such as imagecreatetruecolor().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Answer (score 0):

Painfully simple, issue wasn't with $output but the input variable. I convert the image and resize in which is the `$dst` result.

```
imagejpeg($dst, "$output", 60);
```